# How to refresh a page with DB update or with a post to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page with several controls to present list of books and their details found in the database.
I need the page `books.aspx` to be refreshed once a new book is inserted into the DB.

There is another page `addBook.aspx` which is receiving a post query with the book details, and it's the one adding the book to the database.

I need to refresh the `books.aspx` page with one of the two methods, either from addBook.aspx once it receives a post or by some database trigger once the book is added to the tables.

I have tried using the `updatePannel` and several `JavaScript` methods I found on the web with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into ASP.NET [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) which allows you to do real time updates to your page.

Basically your browser will make a connection to your hub and whenever you add a new book, your code should invoke your client side method with the new book information in JSON format or so, so that you can update your UI with that.

SignalR will use WebSockets under the covers when it's available, and gracefully fallback to other techniques like long polling using javascript setInterval

Comment: Thanks. SignalR is a great solution here as I see an example on youtube.

Answer (score 2):

It may be overkill for you here, but [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) is designed to make this kind of thing much easier.

And you should know that what you're asking for is really contrary to how web pages work. At the most fundamental level, a browser sends an http request to a server. The server builds an html response, and sends it to the browser. The browser receives the response and renders the html.

The thing is: that's really the end of it. By the time the html is rendered, the server has already recycled any resources used to produce that html. Anything beyond this is going to require extra code to manage some kind of heartbeat check via javascript where the browser periodically checks in with the server, and each heartbeat is a whole new request/response cycle. This concept where the server will initiate an update going to the web browser just doesn't exist. The newer WebSocket concept is something of an exception, but even here: SignalR is how you make those work in ASP.Net.

Comment: Thanks alot, looking at some SignalR examples I see that it will be working great for me.

Answer (score 0):

You basically want an ajax type control on the books.aspx page polling every so often to check for updates, once you detect the update you can go from there. It is however a bit of a minefield especially if you're dealing with grids.

Answer (score 0):

So I've struggled with the SignalR and came up with nothing... Basically what I did was:

Added the next to the books.aspx head tag

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var refreshHubJs = $.connection.RefreshHub;
        refreshHubJs.Re = function () {
            window.location.reload();
        }
        $.connection.hub.start();

    </script>
```

Then added the next to the page load function of addBook.aspx

```
var refreshHubContent = Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<RefreshHub>();
            refreshHubContent.Clients.All.RefreshAll();
```

And of course added the hub file with the next content:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

public class RefreshHub : Hub
{
}
```

For it all to run added the Startup.cs file in the root namespace which was generated automatically.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup1))]

public class Startup1
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
    }
}
```

The application works just as before, no errors or problems but the new functionality I tried to add is not present as if I never added it.

I just want for each time someone turns to the file addBook.aspx (for any reason) for the books.aspx to be refreshed.

Comment: So, if SignalR didn't solve your problem, then this is not an answer to your question. You might want to edit your question and include this content, then delete this "answer".